# How to split a string into an array per underscore if exist otherwise per space

Tags: javascript, regex, reactjs

I want to split a `string` into an `array` in javascript based on `four conditions`

1. First I only consider if there was a word between `two underscore` like `_i am 4 word_`
2. Second if there was not any `underscore` then I consider the `spaces`
3. Third `string` between two underscore, as array will remain the first starter underscore.
4. Fourth the `positions` should not be changed (`the order`).

**Example:**

```
const str = "Hi dear, _How are _ you? _ I missed you_. please _  come back, to me _ . _قبول است؟ _";
```

**should be exactly like this:**

```
const splitedStr = ['Hi', 'dear', '_How are', 'you?', '_I missed you' '.', 'please', '_come back, to me', '.', 'قبول است؟'];
```

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Comment: @HermitCrab, thank you to reply I google it completely today, while I don't know about regex I couldn't fix it, although I know there are same questions, but I couldn't bring it to the thing I want so far

Comment: Then, you just want us tell you the answer?

Comment: @JackTing, please kindly dont me discourage for my overcome on problem, I find this best community for asking questions, If I can answer to others never hesitate

Comment: Please do some Google search on "RegExp how to"

Comment: @JackTing thank you, I have google one day and I am still googling, I find a lot of same questions, just there is some cases which I cant fix it.

Comment: There will be no exactly answer for you, you have to learn how to write a regular expression, and do some exercise.  Then post what you have done.

Comment: I think you could also do that with string manipulation methods like split, trim, etc.. You dont have to rely on regexp only.

Comment: @Istnrs, thank you, as @Moon answered it's almost done except one point I mentioned in comment under question. but I think if it would be with `regex` may it be faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this?

```js
function mySplit(str) {
  var result = [];
  str.split("_").forEach((str, index, arr) => {
    if (index % 2 === 0 || index === arr.length - 1) {
      result.push(...str.trim().split(" "));
    } else {
      result.push("_" + str.trim());
    }
  });
  if (str[0] === "_")
    result.shift();
  if (str[str.length - 1] === "_")
    result.pop();
  return result;
}
const tests = [
"Hi dear, _How are _ you? _ I missed you_. please _  come back, to me _ ._good dear",
"Hi dear, _How are _ you? _ I missed you_. please _  come back, to me _ ._good dear_",
"",
"_",
"should double underscores __ <--be like this or empty?",
"outside words _inside words_",
"_apple banana pear_",
"only one _ underscore here"
];
for (i in tests) {
  console.log(`${i}:`, mySplit(tests[i]).join("|"));
}
```

Comment: Thank you this is really well, but a few problem, this only consider first `underscore`, example I added this `string` -> `_good dear` at the end of my current `string` and the output was `[... , "_good dear"]`, which is incorrect because there is not underscore at the end like `_good dear_`. so with `_good dear`. it should be like `[..., "_good", "dear"]` because this has underscore only at the beginning.

Comment: @Muhammad I edited it, hope it works now. The `trim()` calls can be removed if spacing in the text should be preserved.